# Need help fitting a design flow into REST

Tags: ruby-on-rails-3, rest, routes

I'm having a bit of a trouble understanding how to fit a particular design flow I have into a proper REST architecture. Let me explain the flow:

I'm creating technical support website where users can submit **ProblemRequests**. On the front page, the user selects all the categories he's having trouble with and clicks "get help," which then redirects him to the next page where he fills out some forms to submit his request. Here are the pages:

[Page 1 - Select Problem Categories](http://i.minus.com/ijzMDj1LiPxFI.png)

[Page 2 - Fill out Problem Request](http://i.minus.com/ibzdee6NK8hqhV.png)

Page 2 basically acts like the NEW action for a **ProblemRequest**. The thing is each ProblemRequest depends on multiple **ProblemCategories**, so a nested route isn't going to work here. The next thing that comes to mind is sending in all relevant ProblemCategories ids as an GET param for the *NEW* **ProblemRequest** action, but I would rather not expose the IDs in the URL.

A Multi-Part form sort of comes to mind, but that involves making **ProblemRequests** have state, where some would be complete and others incomplete. I don't want to deal with the implications, because in reality this is a one page submission, not a very long-winded process.

What would work ideally is to override the NEW action for the **ProblemRequests controller** to respond to POST operations, but I don't know if this is considered bad programming practice. Is this a cardinal sin? Is it okay for me to change the NEW action to respond to POST instead of GET?

Please advise,

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use a multi-step form: http://railscasts.com/episodes/217-multistep-forms

You can save the IDs in the session, and the model won't get saved in the DB until you are finished filling out the info. Works great for simple 2 or 3 step forms.

For more complex wizards you could use a gem like https://github.com/schneems/wicked

Answer (score 2):

Keep it simple.  Is there any reason for the round-trip to the server?  I'd just make the two "pages" a single page and maintain the state of the selected categories client-side.

Comment: Great answer! However, yes, there is a reason for the trip to the server. The second page has a list of forms, but those forms are dynamic and need to be retrieved from the server. The forms I retrieve, of course, depend on the problem categories selected.

Comment: In that case, I'd just expose the IDs in the URL.  It doesn't grossly violate the spirit of a resource, IMO.  You're simply saying "Give me a form so I can create a record that applies to all these ProblemCategory IDs."  Don't break controller conventions simply for the sake of terse URLs.  Nobody will type the 2nd URL into their browser, and they don't care what the URL is.  I completely understand that such an approach may not feel satisfying, but save your brain cycles for bigger problems.  My 2nd choice would be the POST approach, but I'd rename it entirely if I was breaking convention.